# Error exception 'Undefined index: request' when invoking to upload image

Tags: imgur

I am using the 'j0k3r/php-imgur-api-client' package in my laravel project.
The installation of it seems to be good and lucky.
And I wrote a test seeder script(UnitTestSeeder.php) and a class (ImgurClient.php) as followed：

```
<?php  
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;  
use App\Libs\Service\ImgurClient;    
class UnitTestSeeder extends Seeder{  
    public function run(){  
        $username = 'your_imgur_username';
        $id = 'Iemhfpo';
        //$response = $this->galleryFavorites($username);//run ok
        //$response = $this->favorites($username);// run ok
        //$response = $this->randomGalleryImages();//run ok


        //$response = $this->uploadImage();//run error        
        //$response = $this->createAlbum();//run error

        print_r($response);
    }

    private function uploadImage(){
        $client = new ImgurClient();
        $fpath = storage_path('app/public/test.jpg');
        $imageData = ['image' => $fpath, 'type'  => 'file'];

        return $client->upload($imageData);
    }
    private function createAlbum(){
        $client = new ImgurClient();
        $album_data = [];
        $album_data['title'] = 'Bracelet';
        $album_data['description'] = 'Beautiful Bracelet';
        $album_data['privacy'] = 'public';
        $album_data['layout'] = 'grid';

        return $client->createAlbum($album_data);
    }
    private function randomGalleryImages(){
        $client = new ImgurClient();
        return $client->randomGalleryImages();
    }
    private function galleryFavorites($username){
        $client = new ImgurClient();
        return $client->galleryFavorites($username);
    }
    private function favorites($username){
        $client = new ImgurClient();
        return $client->favorites($username);
    }
```

But saddly, as the code comments showed above, 
Some API calls can't work and some other API calls work well.

The 2 calls(createAlbum and uploadImage) throwed exceptions like this
[Please view my screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDQA7.png)
Anybody have encountered such errors? Thanks all!